# Try out api from devportal but get error " TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource"

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have run API-Manager 4.0.0 by ./api-manager.sh and i get
https://ip:9443/publisher, https://ip:9443/devportal, https://ip:9443/carbon,

I create an api on publisher and subscribe on devporta，but when i try out it by token,
it gives me a response with "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource" ,
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this, Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you deploy the API before publishing? Also try running the curl command from tryout console in your local terminal.

Comment: Yes, i did, I can see deploy icon was green, and i tried running curl command in my local terminal but i got "404***" with http and "ssl certificate***" with https

Comment: Can you add `-k` also to the curl command and see?

Comment: Yes, I got the same 404 response by -k , {"code":"404","type":"Status report","message":"Not Found","description":"The requested resource is not available."}

Comment: This issue comes up when you have not deployed a revision of the API from the Publisher.